# Load TensorFlow FLAGS from file (TF version > 1.4)

Tags: tensorflow, config, flags, abseil

I would like to store `FLAGS` (`tf.app.flags.FLAGS`) in a file and reload them later. Until TensorFlow 1.4, I used this code for reloading:

```py
with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
     config = json.load(f)
     FLAGS.__flags.update(config)
```

From TensorFlow 1.5, the underlying implementation of `FLAGS` changed. Does anybody know a way to update the FLAGS with values stored in a file?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    for name, value in config.items():
        FLAGS.__flags[name].value = value
```